# Sayings similar to "a picture is worth a thousand words"

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

I' m looking for a common saying or catchphrase that has the same meaning as "a picture is worth a thousand words". I need this as a title for an article that illustrates that point in a specific context, but the original is obviously worn out.

EDIT To clarify: I'm trying to illustrate the point that it's easier to convince someone of a fact if you show them it, than if you just describe it.

Comment: Are you asking for something that doesn't exist? I mean, aren't idioms like "a picture is worth a thousand words" around because they meet a language need that isn't otherwise being met?

Comment: @ect No. Just as there are synonymous words, there are synonymous expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest phrase that comes to mind is *“Show, don't tell”*. The meaning is a little different, but it might still be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

How about "Seeing is believing."

Answer (score 1):

If you want your title remain catchy but at the same time that it would not be a platitude, you best either modify it slightly, or completely through some metaphors, obviously depending on your audience and additional information you would like to convey. Some examples for the inspiration:

1. (Playful, traditional, oriental) A picture is worth a thousand and one words.
2. (Playful, modern, Western) A picture is worth a thousand and 42 words.
3. (Modern, technological) A pixel is worth 1024 bits.
4. (Controversial) One Monet worth 1000 Shakespeares.
5. (Scientific) One whiteboard is worth approximately 31415 words.
6. (Inverse) One word is one thousandth of a picture.
7. (Multiplied) 3 pictures are worth 3000 words.
8. (Postmodern) Bargain today: 1 picture for 1000 words!
9. (Everyday life, sayings): 1 picture is worth 365 words.
10. (Postmodern, Stock market): 1 picture closes at 1000.0 words.
11. (Metaphoric): Better to open the eye than to scratch the ear.
12. (Playful on Nietzsche): And those who were watching were thought to be insane by those who just heard the music.

Comment: When you gaze long into an abyss the abyss doesn't gaze back, you know its a bogus abyss?

Comment: @David Toth, this is a great list! By the way, there's a word for this type of wordplay: **anti-proverbs** or **perverbs**!

Answer (score 0):

The soul never thinks without a picture.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that this is a "common saying or catchphrase" as the question requests?

Answer (score 0):

This quote is supposedly attributed to Emperor Napoleon Bonaparte:

**a good sketch is better than a long speech**

In french: "Un bon croquis vaut mieux qu'un long discours".